# Deploy docker-compose project into ECS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-code-deploy

I am attempting to create a pipeline to build and deploy docker-compose applications. I have already completed the CodeBuild portion to push the images to ECR. I'm just not sure what's next. If I need to use CodeDeploy? The code I'm attempting to push is a cookie cutter of https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django

I might be missing something simple but I haven't seen much documentation on deploying docker-compose applications. This is a question that I have been attempting to solve for the last few hours and would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

**ECS does not support natively docker-compose**. Instead it uses its own [task-definitions format](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definitions.html). Thus you have to translate docker-compose.yaml into the task definition.

Having said that, there is ongoing effort from AWS and Docker communities to make docker-compose work. One way how it can be possible is described in the recent **AWS blog**:

- [Deploy applications on Amazon ECS using Docker Compose](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/deploy-applications-on-amazon-ecs-using-docker-compose/)

The approach used in the blog post involves [Docker desktop](https://hub.docker.com/signup/awsedge?utm_source=awsedge).